# Postgis : endless st_intersection

Tags: unit-testing, intersection

I have 2 layers of land use (2006 and 2018) of the Multipolygon type, and a grid of polygons of 100 * 100m of the Polygon type.
These 2 layers are cut on a circle of 10,000 m², are on the Lambert 93, and have a spatial index.

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/49/dlkk.png

The 2006 land use layer contains 14,320 entries, the 2018 land cover approximately 13,000, and the grid 31,000.

In each cell of my grid (and in its strict hold), I want to cut out the land use elements, separately for the 2 different dates (to start). For this, I headed to st_intersection :

```sql
/* 1 */ 
select 
  grille.id as id_carr, 
  2006 as annee, 
  code, 
  st_intersection(occ_2006_test.geom, grille.geom) as geom
from grille, occ_2006_test
where st_intersects(occ_2006_test.geom, grille.geom);
```

```sql
/* 2 */
select 
  grille.id as id_carr, 
  2018 as annee, 
  code, 
  st_intersection(occ_2018_test.geom, grille.geom) as geom
from grille, occ_2018_test
where st_intersects(occ_2018_test.geom, grille.geom);
```

The first query, the one on the 2006 layer, lasts 12 seconds and returns 110,000 rows. The second, for some reason, still turns after 10 minutes ....

How to explain this difference in performance? (the link to access my diapers, if ever ... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RC76v0Dm-iufw_mmA8EGaarO0ZaC4MJw/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you.

Comment: so the queries are the same? Therefore your tables are the difference? Were both tables created exactly the same? You should check the DDL of both the tables to confirm. The second table has no spatial index??   And you could also mention what version of postgresql and postgis you have installed.